# Enable Mailbox Auditing

Tags: powershell, security, office365

When I run this command I'm getting an error on enabling a few accounts for auditing.

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited -Filter {RecipientTypeDetails -eq "UserMailbox" -or RecipientTypeDetails -eq "SharedMailbox" -or RecipientTypeDetails -eq "RoomMailbox" -or RecipientTypeDetails -eq "DiscoveryMailbox"} |
    Set-Mailbox -AuditEnabled $true -AuditLogAgeLimit 180 -AuditAdmin Update, MoveToDeletedItems, SoftDelete, HardDelete, SendAs, SendOnBehalf, Create, UpdateFolderPermission -AuditDelegate Update, SoftDelete, HardDelete, SendAs, Create, Update FolderPermissions, MoveToDeletedItems, SendOnBehalf -AuditOwner UpdateFolderPermission, MailboxLogin, Create, SoftDelete , HardDelete, Update, MoveToDeletedItems
```

Then I get this error here,

```
The operation couldn't be performed because 'Employee Name' matches multiple
entries.
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-Mailbox], ManagementObjectAmbiguousException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=removed,RequestId=removed,TimeStamp=8/16/2018 8:54:51 PM] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-ManagementObjectAmbiguousException] B88862F7,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.SetMailbox
+ PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com
```

Then I'm running this command to see who is enabled and who isn't

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited |
    Select Name, AuditEnabled, AuditLogAgeLimit |
    Out-Gridview
```

Which pops up a GUI and show's me a few Employee's that are duplicate. This is because we have two different domain names with different email boxes. Example: john@company1.com and john@company2.com. How do I enable those duplicate accounts in PowerShell?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find it funny that the identity parameter passed through the pipeline is based on the Name, even though it doesn't uniquely identify the object :) (an Identity should be unique by definition!!). Anyhow, what we need to do is to change the Identity from the name to something more globally unique like the `GUID`. We can do this by adding in a step in the pipeline to change the `Identity`:

```
Get-Mailbox...| Select -Property @{Name="Identity";Expression={$_.GUID.ToString()}}  | Set-Mailbox...
```

What I am doing is to use an expression inside a `Select` statement to convert the `GUID` in to a string, and pass it on through the pipeline as the `Identity`. The `Set-Mailbox` will take the `GUID` as an `Identity`, and will update the right mailbox.

So your code becomes (broken up for clarity):

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited -Filter {RecipientTypeDetails -eq "UserMailbox" -or RecipientTypeDetails -eq "SharedMailbox" -or RecipientTypeDetails -eq "RoomMailbox" -or RecipientTypeDetails -eq "DiscoveryMailbox"}`
| Select -Property @{Name="Identity";Expression={$_.GUID.ToString()}} `
| Set-Mailbox -AuditEnabled $true -AuditLogAgeLimit 180 -AuditAdmin Update, MoveToDeletedItems, SoftDelete, HardDelete, SendAs, SendOnBehalf, Create, UpdateFolderPermissions -AuditDelegate Update, SoftDelete, HardDelete, SendAs, Create, UpdateFolderPermissions, MoveToDeletedItems, SendOnBehalf -AuditOwner UpdateFolderPermissions, MailboxLogin, Create, SoftDelete , HardDelete, Update, MoveToDeletedItems
```

Comment: Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'AuditDelegate'. Cannot convert value "Update
SoftDelete HardDelete SendAs Create Update" to type "Microsoft.Exchange.Data.MultiValuedProperty`1[Micro
soft.Exchange.Data.Directory.MailboxAuditOperations]". Error: "The value 'Update' is already present in
the collection."

Comment: There is a space in `Update FolderPermissions` I fixed it to `UpdateFolderPermissions` under `-AuditDelegate`

Comment: And I think `-AuditOwner UpdateFolderPermission`  and `-AuditAdmin` needs  an "s" at the end as well to `-AuditOwner UpdateFolderPermissions` -updated answer

Comment: Great work Dude, I just ran it and it worked perfect. Giving you credit to the answer! Good Job!